# Using mail flow rules in Office 365

Tags: exchange, office365

I use Office 365 and have a user account with multiple aliases

The main account is user@email.com and the aliases are user1@email.com and user2@email.com etc. (there are about 30 aliases in total).

Is it possible to append the alias to the subject line of inbound emails using mail flow rules so I can see which email address the email was sent to?

e.g. an email sent to user2@email.com would be forwarded to user@email.com with the subject line **[user2@gmail.com] RE: Subject Line**

I know this can be done using mail rules on a email by email address basis but I'm after a solution which does it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to distinguish emails according to different alias, we can set client rules to show which alias an email to sent to.

Please create a rule according to following rule description:

[image]

You can find same was discussed in following thread in TechNet fourm:

[Differentiate Emails Sent to Alias in Inbox](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/159a5021-a2d3-4851-86dd-79f9796138ab/differentiate-emails-sent-to-alias-in-inbox?forum=Office2016setupdeploy)

[How do I move incoming mail addressed to an alias into a user's inbox folder?](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/Windows/en-US/9dbe89ef-a1be-4f89-bef2-7c0412b5668f/how-do-i-move-incoming-mail-addressed-to-an-alias-into-a-users-inbox-folder?forum=exchangesvrgenerallegacy)

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't the server-side solution I'm looking for.